# What is the purpose of IoCompleteRequest?

Tags: winapi, device-driver, dispatch, windows-kernel

Why do many device drivers have an `IoCompleteRequest(irp,IO_NO_INCREMENT);` at the end of the dispatch routines? I read the corresponding Microsoft docs for the `IoCompleteRequest` function, but I didn't understand very well those concepts.

Comment: because Irp must be completed. and always need call `IofCompleteRequest` for Irp. driver need do yourself or pass Irp down to another driver, which by self complete this Irp or pass it to next driver.. etc.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/when-to-complete-an-irp-in-a-dispatch-routine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand the lifecycle of an IRP. How the IRP is created (IoAllocateIrp), delivered (IoCallDriver), and released (IoFreeIrp) after work is done.
Second, if necessary, when post-processing is required at the end of the operation, the processing of the I/O completion routine is also handled in the driver hierarchical manner.
IoCompleteRequest does the job of ensuring these two things.

1. Application performs an I/O request.
2. I/O Manager (create IRP, pass to driver)
3. Driver (IRP complete after processing the job (IoCompleteRequest))
4. I/O Manager (Release IRP, transfer result to upper application)
5. The application receives the I/O result.